# C#: default value for Vector in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, vector, null, monogame

I have the following problem:
I have a classs that takes a position as a Vector2 in its constructor. Now, in some cases I don't know the position and want to change it at another place in the code. Since you can't make a Vector2 = null in C#, is there any default value for a Vector2 to signalize: "This Vector has no Value"?

This is the constructor in question:

`public SoundEvent(SoundEffects sound, Vector2 soundOrigin)`

I want to be able to call this constructor either with the SoundEffect only, or with the SoundEffect and position.

Comment: Can you just add another overload of the method without `soundOrigin` parameter? Or you can use `Nullable<Vector2>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, Nullable<Vector2> was what I was searching for! Overloading the methode should work too, it just would be a bit more complicated in the current code structur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nullable<Vector2>` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Nullable less than Vector2?

Comment: When I type <>, it gets invisible. The answer of @Serg is correct, but you can't flair a comment as solution, so I posted it again as an answer (I still have to wait 2 days unti I can flair my own answer as solution)

Comment: Or perhaps `Vector2? origin = null` would fit better in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way:

```
public SoundEvent(SoundEffects sound, Vector2? soundOrigin = null)
   Vector2 so;
   if (soundOrigin == null)
      so = new Vector2(); // default to origin?
    else
      so = soundOrigin;
```

The extra variable `so` guarantees null uses will not throw errors later.

Comment: The guard is pointless as you would not make soundOrigin nullable if you are going to ensure it has a value.

Comment: My problem was that I could't use a default vector2 here, the purpose of this class is to signal the usage of either a vector2 or an default value elsewhere in the code.